# How to send specific information through sockets separately python

Tags: python, file, sockets

My Question is that I have make a script which sends a file from server to a client. I want to send a specific information, like the name of the file separately to the client without being mixed with the bytes of sent file. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

send it in json format, with the format, name, size etc all in a seperate object called header in the json string and then an object called data which contains the file data

here's an example:

```
class header:
    def __init__(self, name, typ, size):
        self.name = name
        self.type = typ
        self.size = size


class jsonClass:

    def __init__(self, data, name, typ, size):
        self.header = header(name, typ, size)
        self.data = data

data = "data"
name = "name"
typ = "type"
size = "size"

jsonObject = jsonClass(data, name, typ, size)
```

you can now serialize this jsonObject with the json class of python and send it over the socket in binary form(after encoding the string to binary)

You could also store the data as a python Dictionary which can be converted to Json string :

```
jsonObject2= { "header2":{
                    "name":"filename",
                    "size":"filesize"
                },
               "data":"filedata"
              }
```

Comment: Can you give any sample as I am new in Python?

Comment: JSON is not a format for binary data. The example is neither python nor javascript.

Comment: Haven't you read the part at the end that says stringify? you send the string. please read the whole thing before downvoting @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel Sorry about that... it's been a while since I worked with Python. this fix should do

Comment: @Daniel I had meant to use the Python Dictionary actually in the previous example.. guess I messed up on the key values